# Twig, Sandbox SecurityPolicy continue render instead of throwing exception?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to use twig to render a html part that is being added by users, now I wanted to use the SecurityPolicy and only allow certain filters / methods.

```
$tags = ['if', 'for', 'set'];
$filters = ['escape', 'join', 'length', 'escape', 'date'];
$functions = ['range'];

$policy = new \Twig\Sandbox\SecurityPolicy($tags, $filters, [], [], $functions);
$sandbox = new \Twig\Extension\SandboxExtension($policy, true);
$twig = new \Twig\Environment(new \Twig\Loader\ArrayLoader(array('template' => $twigTemplate)));
```

for testing I removed upper from the filters, and tried adding it from the frontend. now when the template is being rendered I get an exception:

```
Type: Twig\Sandbox\SecurityNotAllowedFilterError
Message: Filter "upper" is not allowed.
```

this is great, it notices the upper filter is being used, but I was hoping to get a more user friendly solution.

I would like to just skip the unallowed filters / functions / tags, and continue rendering the page, does anyone have an idea if that's possible?

ideally it would just render the twig template and display the unallowed tags as they were so {{ "test" |upcase }} for instance would just be displayed like that..

Comment: I hope you're aware, that what you apparently want, is to replace built-in filters with some "dummy" filter, that doesn't do anything. That has its very own implications, because certain filters don't just change case but change type and stuff, so in order to to allow blacklisted (non-whitelisted) filters and tags, you would have to implement the dummy version yourself,  because when twig encounters something it can't render, it must throw something, because "do nothing" is completely unclear for certain stuff. for example `join` turn's an array into a string. what would twig do instead?

Comment: I have chosen to keep with the sandbox mode and do the render in a try catch, then don't save the document and return the exception message to the user (for instance, filter join not allowed)

it works allright like this.

Comment: it's probably the better solution, tbh. good choice! ;o)